# Tag merge request

Tags: support

I can't seem to figure out tag merging, I'm just full of fail today.

Can you make `aam` be a synonym of `alternate-access-mapping`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! I've merged [aam](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aam) to [alternate-access-mapping](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-access-mapping) and it is now a synonym.